# sed conditional replace single character csv file

Tags: replace, sed

The problem is removing , errors in text files.
The error is the ',' after M.D

> xxx","M.D,","abc","xxx

The desired string is to replace the single , after D with a .

> xxx","M.D.","abc","xxx

There are over 30 fields in the line

Comment: `sed 's/"M.D,"/"M.D."/g'` may be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know all your cases but for inits this may work

```
$ echo 'xxx","M.D,","abc","xxx' | sed -r 's/([A-Z]),/\1./'
xxx","M.D.","abc","xxx
```

Comment: Thank you. Briefly what is the purpose of the ( ) around the [A-Z] and the \1. in the replacement set.

Comment: `()` captures the matched char and `\1` is to refer this.  Essentially it's find and replace with referring to the searched pattern.

Answer (score 1):

As an **alternate** solution try this [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) command as follows;

```
sed 's/M.D,/M.D./g' filename
```

**Output:**

```
$ sed 's/M.D,/M.D./g' sample

xxx","M.D.","abc","xxx
```